# How do I get CSS media queries to work correctly on Outlook/Gmail?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, html-email

It appears that when I code the below into an email and send it, Outlook and Gmail (and probably other desktop email clients) render *both* tables (**which is the problem I'm trying to solve for**).  But, when I view on my mobile, it complies with the CSS media queries and *only* displays the table element with a class of "mobile".  I am unsure why this is, am I doing anything wrong?  Here's my code:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 0px) {
        table[class="desktop"] {
            display: none;
        }

        table[class="mobile"] {
            display: block;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 4000px) and (min-width: 481px) {
        table[class="desktop"] {
            display: block;
        }

        table[class="mobile"] {
            display: none;
        }
    }
</style>
<table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="desktop">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4">Standard Option
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="4" align="right" style="text-align: center;">NON-POSTAL PREMIUM
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Code</td>
        <td>Biweekly</td>
        <td>Monthly (Retirees)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Self Only</td>
        <td>341</td>
        <td>$57.84</td>
        <td>$125.31</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Self Plus One</td>
        <td>343</td>
        <td>$124.35</td>
        <td>$269.42</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table border="1" cellpadding="" cellspacing="0" width="480" class="mobile">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>Standard Option (NON-POSTAL PREMIUM)</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br style="clear: both;" />
            <table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Self Only</b></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Code</td>
                    <td>341</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Biweekly</td>
                    <td>$57.84</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Monthly (Retirees)</td>
                    <td>$125.31</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br style="clear: both;" />
            <table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

                <tr>
                    <td><b>Self Plus One</b></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Code</td>
                    <td>343</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Biweekly</td>
                    <td>$124.35</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Monthly (Retirees)</td>
                    <td>$269.42</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            <br style="clear: both;" />
            <table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Self and Family</b></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Code</td>
                    <td>343</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Biweekly</td>
                    <td>$136.78</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Monthly (Retirees)</td>
                    <td>$296.36</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a screenshot of Outlook's rendering:

[image]

And here's a screenshot of my mobile device's rendering:

[image]

Comment: Media queries work on Gmail (if coded right) but doesn't work with Outlook. What are you using to send tests?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Outlook does not really have any solid support for media queries unfortunately and is often 'left out' when it comes to mobile responsive emails.

This link [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/mobile/) should help in explaining email responsivity and givs you a good amount of detail.

To create html emails, I often use third party software because coding for different mail clients is a real pain.
I use [beefree.io](https://beefree.io/) to create email templates which I can just download in HTML 5 format.

Comment: Sure thing! Glad to help

Comment: In addition, not all versions of Android support `@media` queries. Gmail has some  issues where it will strip out a style sheet with `@` declaration within an `@`  declaration. Read this for more information: https://emails.hteumeuleu.com/troubleshooting-gmails-responsive-design-support-ad124178bf81 Good luck.